# C# Function with optional and params values

Tags: c#, function, overloading

I have this test code:

```
    void func1(string a, params string[] p)
    {
        func1(a, true, p);
    }

    void func1(string a, bool b, params string[] p)
    {
        //...
    }

    void func2(string a, bool b = true, params string[] p)
    {
        //...
    }

    void exec()
    {
        func1("a", "p1", "p2");
        func2("a", "p1", "p2");
    }
```

Is `func1` and `func2` equals?

There are no errors when I create the `func2`, but, when I try to use the `func2` like in exec (using the optional value), the compiler show an error `This function has some invalid arguments`.

I think that `func1` and `func2` are equal for someone that will consume this function like an API.

What is wrong with this code?
Can I use this approach for functions that have optional and params values?

Comment: I like the question... But please think twice before actually writing such code - you already have trouble to reason what and how will be called while you just wrote the code. Imagine when someone else (or even you 2 month later) will try to use it... You really don't want comment in your coding guidelines "Always specify all arguments to XXXX function because otherwise you'll get strange errors/unpredictable behavior ..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally optional parameters have to come at the end of a method declaration - a parameter array (such as `p` here) is the only exception to that. But when it comes to using the *arguments*, the compiler will assume that all positional arguments are in the same order as the method declaration... so you get into trouble if you want to use the optionality *and* the parameter array side. This should be okay:

```
func2("a", p: new[] { "p1", "p2" })
```

but personally I'd just steer clear of mixing parameter arrays and optional parameters. It's clearly confusing.

I believe the relevant section of the C# 5 specification is 7.5.1.1, which includes:

> A positional argument of a function member with a parameter array invoked in its expanded form, where no fixed parameter occurs at the same position in the parameter list, corresponds to an element of the parameter array.

See also section 7.5.3.1. It's all pretty complicated...

Comment: OK, but about my first question, `func1` is equal to `func2`? I can't see the difference.

Comment: @BrunoCroysFelthes: You'd have to define what you mean by "equal" first. They're clearly not "equal" in that `func1` has two overloads whereas `func2` only has one...